# How to efficiently replace these imdb movie title IDs with the actual title based on a column match?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, imdb

I've been working in R with some IMDB data that they publish, and have been stuck on this for embarrassingly long today.

```
primaryName     tconst                 primaryTitle                          knownForTitles
1          Aaron Lim  tt2317744            My Friend Bernard tt0268228,tt0891369,tt2317744,tt3709694
2      Aaron Woodley  tt3228088          Spark: A Space Tail tt0326065,tt1650535,tt4426464,tt3228088
3 Abdelkader Belhedi tt11069302       The Carthage Castaways         tt11698758,tt11069302,tt0485746
```

I am struggling to come up with a way to match the `knownForTitles` IDs with the ID in the `tconst` column. After matching, I would like to replace the IDs in `knownForTitles` with the actual title names from `primaryTitle`, like below.

```
primaryName     tconst                 primaryTitle                          knownForTitles
1          Aaron Lim  tt2317744            My Friend Bernard Movie Title,Movie Title,Movie Title,Movie Title
2      Aaron Woodley  tt3228088          Spark: A Space Tail Movie Title,Movie Title,Movie Title,Movie Title
3 Abdelkader Belhedi tt11069302       The Carthage Castaways         Movie Title,Movie Title,Movie Title
```

I can only think of using a bunch of for loops which may be very inefficient for thousands of rows. If anyone can point me in a better direction that'd be awesome.

Comment: Can you share a few rows of your data using `dput()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is this. The explanation is below.

**Code**.

```
df = data.frame(primaryName = c("Aaron Lim", "Aaron Woodley"), tconst = c("tt2317744", "tt3228088"), primaryTitle = c("My friend Ron", "Spark: Some Title"), knownForTitles = c("tt0268228,tt0891369,tt2317744,tt3709694", "tt0326065,tt1650535,tt4426464,tt3228088"))
df$tconst = as.character(df$tconst)
Names = df %>%  
  mutate(V2 = strsplit(as.character(knownForTitles), ",")) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(V2) %>% 
  select(-knownForTitles) %>% 
  as.data.frame(.) 
Movies = df[,2:3]
Modi = left_join(Names, Movies, by = c("V2" = "tconst")) 
Modi$primaryTitle.y = as.character(Modi$primaryTitle.y)
Modi[is.na(Modi$primaryTitle.y), "primaryTitle.y"] = "Test"

Modi %>% 
  group_by(tconst) %>%  
  summarise(primNew = stringr::str_c(primaryTitle.y, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  inner_join(df, .)
```

**Output**.

```
    primaryName    tconst      primaryTitle                          knownForTitles
1     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0268228,tt0891369,tt2317744,tt3709694
2 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt0326065,tt1650535,tt4426464,tt3228088
                              primNew
1     Test, Test, My friend Ron, Test
2 Test, Test, Test, Spark: Some Title
```

---

**Explanation**.

Let's define some toy data.

```
    df = data.frame(primaryName = c("Aaron Lim", "Aaron Woodley"), 
                    tconst = c("tt2317744", "tt3228088"), 
                    primaryTitle = c("My friend", "Spark"), 
                    knownForTitles = c("tt0268228,tt0891369,tt2317744,tt3709694", "tt0326065,tt1650535,tt4426464,tt3228088"))
    df$tconst = as.character(df$tconst)
```

Then you can take tidyr's `unnest` function to split all the column strings into rows, like this

```
Names = df %>%  
  mutate(V2 = strsplit(as.character(knownForTitles), ",")) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(V2) %>% 
  select(-knownForTitles) %>% 
  as.data.frame(.)
```

with the result

```
> Names
    primaryName    tconst      primaryTitle        V2
1     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0268228
2     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0891369
3     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt2317744
4     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt3709694
5 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt0326065
6 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt1650535
7 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt4426464
8 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt3228088
```

Then you get the movie names for all `tconstants` with

```
Movies = df[,2:3]
Modi = left_join(Names, Movies, by = c("V2" = "tconst"))
```

and the result

```
    primaryName    tconst    primaryTitle.x        V2    primaryTitle.y
1     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0268228              <NA>
2     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0891369              <NA>
3     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt2317744     My friend Ron
4     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt3709694              <NA>
5 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt0326065              <NA>
6 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt1650535              <NA>
7 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt4426464              <NA>
8 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt3228088 Spark: Some Title
```

As this is toy data there are `NA` values which cause some trouble, so we do

```
Modi$primaryTitle.y = as.character(Modi$primaryTitle.y)
Modi[is.na(Modi$primaryTitle.y), "primaryTitle.y"] = "Test"
```

to cope with that.

Finally, you modify the matched movies and collapse them in one row with

```
Modi %>% 
  group_by(tconst) %>%  
  summarise(primNew = stringr::str_c(primaryTitle.y, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  inner_join(df, .)
```

and the result

```
    primaryName    tconst      primaryTitle                          knownForTitles
1     Aaron Lim tt2317744     My friend Ron tt0268228,tt0891369,tt2317744,tt3709694
2 Aaron Woodley tt3228088 Spark: Some Title tt0326065,tt1650535,tt4426464,tt3228088
                              primNew
1     Test, Test, My friend Ron, Test
2 Test, Test, Test, Spark: Some Title
```

Answer (score 2):

We can get the data in `separate_rows`, `match` `knownForTitles` with `tconst` get the corresponding `primaryTitle` value and collapse data together for each `Name`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(knownForTitles, sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(knownForTitles = primaryTitle[match(knownForTitles, tconst)]) %>%
  group_by(primaryName) %>%
  summarise(knownForTitles = toString(na.omit(knownForTitles)))
```

---

In base R, we can split the string and `match`

```
df$knownForTitles <- sapply(strsplit(df$knownForTitles, ','), function(x) 
                 with(df, toString(na.omit(primaryTitle[match(x, tconst)]))))
```

Comment: Ronak, so sorry I'm so tardy. I believe something is misfiring in the last step of your `dplyr` explanation? I get a df with 1 row 1 obs with all of the strings in one

Comment: @moolz Yes, I think that is because you have loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr` hence it is asking the function `summarise`. Can you restart R and load only `dplyr` and check the above or use `dplyr::summarise(knownForTitles = toString(na.omit(knownForTitles)))` in last line.